# Minor tweaking of code for excel "Rollup"

Tags: excel, rollup, vba

I have the code from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/libr...ice.12%29.aspx

for making a Rollup (Merging Data from Multiple Workbooks into a Summary Workbook in Excel) it works great but I need some help in tweaking it.

I need the destination file (The Rollup file) to start on the second row, now it starts on the first row.

I have column headers on the first row and they are being over written.

It is a long piece of code but it is well annotated, I have tried for a couple of hours to get what I want but have had no luck.

I susspect this is a part that need changing

```
 ' Set the destination range.
      Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

       ' Copy the values from the source range
       ' to the destination range.
        With sourceRange
             Set destrange = destrange. _
                                       Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                 End With
                 destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                 rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                End If
```

Thanks

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
 Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
 Dim MyFiles() As String
 Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
 Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
 Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
 Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

 ' Change this to the path\folder location of your files.
 MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

 ' Add a slash at the end of the path if needed.
 If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    MyPath = MyPath & "\"
 End If

 ' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
 FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
 If FilesInPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
 End If

 ' Fill the myFiles array with the list of Excel files
 ' in the search folder.
 FNum = 0
 Do While FilesInPath <> ""
    FNum = FNum + 1
    ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
    MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
    FilesInPath = Dir()
 Loop

 ' Set various application properties.
 With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
 End With

 ' Add a new workbook with one sheet.
 Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
 rnum = 1

 ' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
 If FNum > 0 Then
    For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
        Set mybook = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
            On Error Resume Next

            ' Change this range to fit your own needs.
            With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
            End With

            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                Set sourceRange = Nothing
            Else
                ' If source range uses all columns then 
                ' skip this file.
                If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                End If
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                    MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                    GoTo ExitTheSub
                Else

                    ' Copy the file name in column A.
                    With sourceRange
                        BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(FNum)
                    End With

                    ' Set the destination range.
                    Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                    ' Copy the values from the source range
                    ' to the destination range.
                    With sourceRange
                        Set destrange = destrange. _
                                        Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                    End With
                    destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                    rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                End If
            End If
            mybook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If

    Next FNum
    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
 End If

ExitTheSub:
 ' Restore the application properties.
 With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `rnum = 1` to `rnum = 2` about 30 lines from beginning?

Comment: Thank you Doug, that moved the data down to the second row.  But the headers in row one are being erased when the code is run. Is the away to prevent this? i.e to keep the row1 headers.

Comment: This line creates a new workbook and worksheet:  `Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)` so BaseWks is a brand-new worksheet. I don't see where the headers are added. How are you adding them? You could add the header row in code.

Comment: Oops never mind. I see that you are adding it from a template?

Comment: I have a excel file I call Rollup, I this file I have added the code above. I have the headers on row one of sheet1 in this file.  Does this anwser your question?

Comment: If there is a way to add the headers with code I happy to do that

Comment: I see now that previous comment was right and that BaseWks is always a new blank worksheet. So, yes, I'll add an answer that creates the headers in code in just a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These changes will start your data on row 2 and add headers to sheet1 of your newly created workbook:

First, add this to your variable declarations:

```
Dim Headers As Variant
Dim i As Long
```

And modify your code below to:

```
' Add a new workbook with one sheet.
Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
rnum = 2
Headers = Array("Workbook", "header2", "header3")
For i = LBound(Headers) To UBound(Headers)
    BaseWks.Cells(1, i + 1) = Headers(i)
Next i
```

You need, of course, to change the number and text of headers to suit your case.